# why does adding an LDA document vector with a word2vec word vector work well in LDA2vec?

Tags: classification, nlp, word-embeddings, word2vec, lda

In LDA the document weight vector represents the "weights" of each topic in the document. I think it's also valid to say, each row in the document vector corresponds to a word in the document, the weight value being indicative of how relevant each word is to the topics being discussed in the document.

[image]

where dj is some document vector in the form

[image]

[image]

from my understanding, LDA2vec tries to minimize the cost function by  shifting the p_jk weights of the document vector such that the sum w_j dot c_j for j = 0...n is minimal, which makes sense. I just don't understand the relationship between LDA space and the space of word vectors, because from the way it's being described it seems like the rows of the word vectors carry the same meaning as the rows of the document vectors in LDA, and I don't understand why that would be. If anyone can clear the confusion, that would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Update:

After further thought, the only way this would make sense to me is if the word, topic, and document vectors weights were being jointly trained and therefore belonging in a common space. Not sure if this is the case though.